# Missing files when running C++ with makefile on cgwin

Tags: c++, windows, makefile

**Task**: Run examples from here: https://github.com/mesoscale/mmsp

**Done**:

- Running 'make'  builds the .exe file
- Dependency Walker to see which files are missing. Mostly, DLL files.
- Added "cygwin1.dll" to windows env paths and worked fine, don't want to donwload each of this .dll's one by one

**Results**:

- After building .exe file, it won't run. Added file to dependency walker to show what might be wrong.

**Screenshots**:

[image: Dependancy walker missing files]

Comment: We need to see the tree starting with your app, not partway down the Windows system components.  Note also that Dependency Walker does not cope with the DLL versioning now in use (it's not been updated for a while).  All the system DLLs are present but without the version(s) in their filenames.

Comment: I will suggest to start slowly and make sure that you understand or find the root of the problem in terms of linking ... it will be nice if you can provide a sample case you tried instead of a screenshot (makefile and the corresponding sources).

Comment: Thanks, edited question to show what I'm trying to do and what I've done, I'm noob on this, thanks in advance!